VBA/Excel Where Excel did automatic recalculation
Is there any way to determine where exactly Excel performed the recalculation?
That is, in which cells, on which sheets after entering a new value?
Real use-case:
I need to record the values of all cells entered by the user in the database using an event driven macro, however, I also need to record changes in cells that are formulas and have been recalculated.  But I was not able to find this information anywhere in excel.
Thanks for the help
Using worksheet_calculate I can do this on a specific sheet (I simply search the cells if they have formulas and then compare their current and past values), however, this is computationally intensive if I have to search all sheets (tents) for each entered value...

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.


In order to "determine where exactly Excel performed the recalculation" a Calculate event exists in any sheet code module and a SheetCalculate exists in ThisWorbook code module. This last one has a parameter to identify the sheet you need to monitor (if more then one...):

Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
   If Sh.Name = "MySheet" or Sh.Name = "Sheet100" then
     'do something
   end if
End Sub


You can invoke Calculate from your code to:


All open workbooks    Application.Calculate
A specific worksheet  Worksheets("MySheet").Calculate
A specified range Worksheets("MySheet").Range("A2:B20").Calculate

In order to Calculate cells having formula from a specific range in a sheet, you can use:
Sub TestCalculateFormula()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, rngForm As Range
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  Set rngForm = sh.Range("A2:E20").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    Debug.Print rngForm.address 'just to see that it returns correctly
    
  rngForm.Calculate

If you want comparing values of cells containing formula, after calculation, you need to place the existing in a range (array, if the range is continuous) and then compare the values. Something like:
Private rngExisting As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
  If rngExisting Is Nothing Then
    Set rngExisting = Me.Range("A2:E20").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    MsgBox "This is first time when using this event and it only creates the reference range..."
    Exit Sub
  End If
  Dim rngUpdated, celEx As Range, celUpd As Range
  Set rngUpdated = Me.Range("A2:E20").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
  For Each celEx In rngExisting
    For Each celUpd In rngUpdated
        If Not celEx.value = celUpd.value Then
           Debug.Print celEx.address & " / " & celEx.value & vbCrLf & _
                       celUpd.address & " / " & celUpd.value
            'do something
            Stop 'just stopping to see what is happening
        End If
    Next celUpd
  Next celEx
End Sub

Now, depending on your specific ranges to be compared, if not discontinued, in order to make the code faster you can use arrays instead of ranges...
